# How to generate java code from uml class diagram in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

Is there any way(maybe plugin) to generate java code from uml class diagram, which I can create in Intellij Idea?

Answer (score 0):

The UML diagram that you can create in IntelliJ IDEA using its built-in diagram support always reflects the structure of actual classes and methods in your application. If you see a class on the UML diagram, then it already exists in your Java code, and there is nothing to generate.

Comment: I can create class diagram of classes, which doesn't exist in project. For example, I create empty project and then I create class diagram , and then I want to generate java code from it.